# How to specify multiple Directory Sources in the .cargo/config.toml file in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Normally, if you wish `cargo` to use vendored code for external dependencies (instead of reaching into [crates.io](https://crates.io/) or `$CARGO_HOME/registry/cache`), you add the following into your `.cargo/config.toml` file :

```ini
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "vendored-sources"

[source.vendored-sources]
directory = "relative/path/to/director/source" # relative to parent of .cargo directory
```

With `relative/path/to/directory/source` containing the vendored packages (along with their own dependencies), as sub-directories containing the contents of unpacked `.crate` files.

**My objective** is to specify more than one `directory` for `[source.vendored-sources]` above. Or just in general, specify multiple Directory Sources for `cargo` to check for vendored code, when building a package.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should just be able to add more directory sources: 
`[source.more-vendored-sources]
directory = "more-vendored-sources"`

Comment: But will those be used? [source.vendored-sources] is used because I replaced [source.crates-io] with it.

Comment: That would be my assumption, though I don't know off-hand

Comment: You should be able use the `more-vendored-sources` by referencing it directly in your dependency declarations, like `some-crate = { version = "0.1.0", registry = "more-vendored-sources" }`.

Comment: @JonasFassbender that didn't work. It says it couldn't parse the relevant package's `Cargo.toml` because of `no index found for registry: more-vendored-sources`.

Comment: Hmm I see. Could you try using [`cargo-local-registry`](https://github.com/dhovart/cargo-local-registry) instead of `cargo vendor` to create your vendored sources? You must use `local-registry="path/to/local/registry"` instead of `directory="..."` in the `[source.more-vendored-sources]` table. Local registries contain an [index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/source-replacement.html#local-registry-sources). It may still not be enough, because we haven't defined a `more-vendored-resources` [`registry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#registries).

Comment: By the way, if your goal is to have source replacement for two distinct Rust projects, rather than one project with multiple vendors, you can have local configuration for each of those projects. You'd have to create a local file `.cargo/config.toml` in each of your projects and do the source replacement there, instead of globally in your `$CARGO_HOME/config.toml`.

Comment: @JonasFassbender local source replacement is what I do. I have a "library" package where I first vendor packages (and their own dependencies) into their own sub-folders (eg. rand has 7 dependencies of it's own, they go into the "rand" subfolder). This is my offline collection.

Then as needed, I copy and paste sub/dependencies into the local "vendor" folder inside a package.

Thing is that within the local "vendor" folder, everything gets mixed up. I would prefer every dependency and it's sub-dependencies to have a separate sub folder within "vendor",

Comment: In fact, if it were possible to add multiple directories as vendor sources , I could even directly refer to folders within my "library" package without having to copy the sources of dependencies locally.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of this writing, users have no control over how a directory source discovers packages.

From [the Cargo API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/cargo/sources/directory/struct.DirectorySource.html):

> `DirectorySource` at this moment is just a root directory containing
> other directories, which contain the source files of packages.